# Trouble with objects inside of objects and maintaining one instance of an object

Tags: c++, object, vector

Having some trouble with passing instances of objects around in other objects.  In the end of the main application I want iDogClassOne and iDogClassTwo to reference the same object and I want that object to contain the numbers that were placed in variableA.  What am I doing wrong here?  The addresses of tempDogClass, iDogClassOne, and iDOgClassTwo are all different so I am pretty sure I am currently creating 3 instances of the dog class which I don't want to do.....  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class dogClass{
public:
    void setVariableA(std::vector<double> newNum) {
        variableA.push_back(newNum);
    }
    void printVariableA() {
        if (variableA.size() != 0) {
            std::cout << variableA[0][0] << std::endl;
            std::cout << variableA[0][1] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    dogClass &dogClass::operator=(const dogClass &src) {
        variableA = src.variableA;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> variableA;
};

class animalClass{
public:
    void addNumberToDog(std::vector<double> num) {
        dogClass tempDogClass;
        getDogOne(tempDogClass);
        tempDogClass.setVariableA(num);
        std::cout << "Address of temp Dog: " << &tempDogClass << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Variables in tempDog:\n";
        tempDogClass.printVariableA();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    void getDogOne(dogClass &dogOne) {
        dogOne = dogs[0];
    }
    void setDogOne(dogClass &dogOne) {
        dogs.push_back(dogOne);
    }
private:
    std::vector<dogClass> dogs;
};


int main() {
    animalClass iAnimalClass;
    dogClass iDogClassOne;

    iAnimalClass.setDogOne(iDogClassOne);

    std::vector<double> newNum;
    newNum.push_back(12);
    newNum.push_back(15);

    iAnimalClass.addNumberToDog(newNum);

    dogClass iDogClassTwo;

    iAnimalClass.getDogOne(iDogClassTwo);

    //Why are these not equal.  Also why does dog Two not contain the values in dog One?
    std::cout << "Address of dog One: " << &iDogClassOne << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Variables in dog One:\n";
    iDogClassOne.printVariableA();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address of dog Two: " << &iDogClassTwo << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Variables in dog Two:\n";
    iDogClassTwo.printVariableA();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

output of console application (why does iDogClassOne and iDogClassTwo not contain the numbers?  also why are tempDog, iDogClassOne, and iDogClassTwo not the same object?)

```
Address of temp Dog: 00000000002AF8A0
Variables in tempDog:
12
15

Address of dog One: 00000000002AF938
Variables in dog One:

Address of dog Two: 00000000002AF920
Variables in dog Two:
```

Comment: You are adding numbers to your tempDog instances and not for dogOne and DogTwo Instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are making copies of the `dogClass` objects in many places.
Please think about the difference of values, references and pointers.
For example in the `main()` function you call `iAnimalClass.setDogOne(iDogClassOne);` The argument is passed as reference, that is ok. But then you **copy** it into the vector. This is little bit tricky because you cannot pass the reference in a vector. In this case you will have to use a vector of pointers to `dogClass`.

Now you already have two instances of `dogClass`. One in the main function, another one in the vector of the `animalClass`.

The next problem is in the `main()` function where you **instantiate** `iDogClassTwo`.

Now you have three instances of `dogClass`.

Then you call `iAnimalClass.getDogOne(iDogClassTwo);` which copies the dog from the vector to the dog in the main function.

Here is the corrected Version:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class dogClass{
public:
    void setVariableA(std::vector<double> newNum) {
        variableA.push_back(newNum);
    }
    void printVariableA() {
        if (variableA.size() != 0) {
            std::cout << variableA[0][0] << std::endl;
            std::cout << variableA[0][1] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    dogClass & operator=(const dogClass &src) {
        variableA = src.variableA;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> variableA;
};

class animalClass{
public:
    void addNumberToDog(std::vector<double> num) {
        dogClass& tempDogClass = getDogOne();
        tempDogClass.setVariableA(num);
        std::cout << "Address of temp Dog: " << &tempDogClass << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Variables in tempDog:\n";
        tempDogClass.printVariableA();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    dogClass& getDogOne() {
        return *dogs[0];
    }
    void setDogOne(dogClass &dogOne) {
        dogs.push_back(&dogOne);
    }
private:
    std::vector<dogClass*> dogs;
};


int main() {
    animalClass iAnimalClass;
    dogClass iDogClassOne;

    iAnimalClass.setDogOne(iDogClassOne);

    std::vector<double> newNum;
    newNum.push_back(12);
    newNum.push_back(15);

    iAnimalClass.addNumberToDog(newNum);

    dogClass& iDogClassTwo = iAnimalClass.getDogOne();

    //Why are these not equal.  Also why does dog Two not contain the values in dog One?
    std::cout << "Address of dog One: " << &iDogClassOne << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Variables in dog One:\n";
    iDogClassOne.printVariableA();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address of dog Two: " << &iDogClassTwo << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Variables in dog Two:\n";
    iDogClassTwo.printVariableA();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help.  It works now and makes sense the mistakes I was making.

Answer (score 0):

> why does iDogClassOne and iDogClassTwo not contain the numbers?

```
int main()
{
    animalClass iAnimalClass;
    dogClass iDogClassOne;

    iAnimalClass.setDogOne(iDogClassOne);  // pushes a copy of iDogClassOne 
                                           // into a vector animalClass::dogs

    std::vector<double> newNum;
    newNum.push_back(12);
    newNum.push_back(15);

    iAnimalClass.addNumberToDog(newNum);  // Only operates on function local variable
                                          // variable tempDogClass without having
                                          // any effect on the outside world.

    dogClass iDogClassTwo;

    iAnimalClass.getDogOne(iDogClassTwo); // copies the copy of iDogClassOne earlier pushed 
                                          // into the vector animalClass::dogs to iDogClassTwo

    std::cout << "Address of dog One: " << &iDogClassOne << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Variables in dog One:\n";
    iDogClassOne.printVariableA();
    std::cout << "\nAddress of dog Two: " << &iDogClassTwo << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Variables in dog Two:\n";
    iDogClassTwo.printVariableA();
}
```

> why are tempDog, iDogClassOne, and iDogClassTwo not the same object?

Why are a, b and c not the same object in following example?

```
void func()
{
    int c;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    func();
}
```